# Converting degrees minutes seconds to seconds?

Tags: trigonometry

If I want to convert 9 degrees 9 minutes and 9 seconds to seconds would I get 32,409.15 seconds?

Comment: How do you obtain a decimal part?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that 1 degree is $3600$ seconds, one minute is $60$ seconds, and a second is a second.

So, the conversion will be: $9\cdot 3600 + 9\cdot 60 + 9$.

This becomes:
$$32400 + 540+9 = 32\,949$$

So, 9 degrees 9 minutes 9 seconds is, when converted to seconds, $32\,949$ (seconds), not $32\,409.15$.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3600 seconds in a degree and 60 seconds in a minute. Therefore, you have $9*3600+9*60+9 = 32949$ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Definitelly not! In the angle $9^{\circ}9'9''$ there have to be an integral number of seconds.

$$9+9\cdot 60+9\cdot 60^2= 32949$$